# Which has a greater entropy?

Tags: equilibrium, entropy

Which of the following has greater entropy?

a.  $\ce{CH3COOH~ (aq)}$

or

b.  $\ce{CH3COO^{-}~ (aq) + H+~(aq)}$

They are both in the same state, and have the same number of particles.. so how do I figure this out? My instinct says a, because the products will be more "random", but I'm not completely sure.. Any ideas?

Comment: Your welcome, glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

In the gas phase I would suspect that the entropies would be equal as both systems have the same number of translational, rotational and vibrational modes (18).

However you specifically ask about the liquid phase system, since you show that both "a" and "b" are solvated in aqueous media. In this case, the ionized molecule (b) has charges on both ions and this will cause increased ordering of the solvent molecules surrounding the ions, more so than neutral molecule "a".  This increased ordering of the system in case "b" will reduce the entropy of the system.  Consequently system "a" will have greater entropy.

Comment: I don't think your statement for the gas phase is correct. Even though both systems might have the same number of degrees of freedom the entropy is not the same for translation, rotation and vibration. I plan to provide an answer to your question "Can Entropy Increase During Bond Formation?" when I get the time and this answer will also deal with this topic.

Comment: @Philipp  Great, I look forward to reading it!

Comment: entropy != disorder.  I also hope you are not seriously suggesting orderly arrangement has any meaning in a normal aqueous solution.  The solvent separated ion pair will have more solvent molecules involved in the interaction than the neutral molecule leading to a greater number of available microstates, leading to a higher entropy.

Comment: @Lighthart  Yes, I am suggesting that the orderly arrangement has entropic significance.  Are you saying that system B is less ordered than A and consequently B has higher entropy?  If so, perhaps you could elaborate your comment into an answer.

Comment: I am not saying anything about order.  Order is not related to entropy in any way.  Entropy is the number of available microstates-- the number of possible ways to arrange items in the system.  When there are more parts, there are necessarily more ways to arrange the parts, and hence larger entropy.  Thus, entropy favors dissociation.

Comment: @Lighthart  Due to the electrostatic charges on the 2 ions when the acetic acid is ionized, aren't there fewer microstates available to the solvent molecules then there are for the solvent molecules when the acetic acid is unionized?

Comment: I would say no.  The covalent bond severely restricts the number of available cofigurations as compared to the dissociated, solvent-solvated ion pair.  Furthermore, in aqueous solution, the cation and anion may 'switch partners' with other solvated ion pairs, further increasing the number of configurations.  Similarly the solvent molecules may exchange amongst themselves.  A slightly different question is proton exchange between hydronium ions and neutral waters, but that process is fast on the timescale of defining microstates.  Unfortunately, I can't seem to find a tabulated value.

Comment: This page: https://www.chem.tamu.edu/class/majors/tutorialnotefiles/entropy.htm  suggests solvation of ammonium nitrate is entropically favored (ie entropy increases).  It is a poor model at best.

Comment: The problem posed by the OP compares acetic acid already in solution vs. ionized acetic acid in solution, so there is no entropic contribution due to addition of acetic acid to the water to consider.  [This link](https://www.boundless.com/chemistry/textbooks/boundless-chemistry-textbook/solutions-12/properties-of-solutions-92/solutions-and-entropy-changes-398-4985/) in the section "Entropy in Solution Formation" notes that "there is a loss of entropy associated with the water molecules organizing their 'solvent cages' around the ions". I was guessing that

Comment: the entropic decrease due to this fairly long-range ordering outweighs the entropic increase due to ionization, but it is just an educated guess on my part.

Comment: Similar viewpoint, just opposite.  I also no longer have a lab to run the experiment, which given the two positions presented, I think is necessary to resolve.